# Does the adjective "Arabian" refer to the people or to the location?

Tags: adjectives, demonyms, locatives

*Arab* and *Arabian* are both related to people:

> - He is an Arab.
> - He is an Arabian.

Which is used for the location of a country?

> - Egypt is an Arab country.
> - Egypt is an Arabian country.

Comment: Both could be. Are you talking about the people or the location?

Comment: I am talking about location.

Comment: I'll try an edit. Revert if you don't like it.

Comment: I've edited this (sorry @ItWasLikeThat): it's possible that it might actually give you the answer.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - I'm fine with your edit - I think my answer still works.

Comment: No different than many other cases.  Does "French" refer to the people or to the location?  Or to the language?

Answer (score 2):

“Egypt is an Arab country” would be grammatically correct if you were referring to the people, though linking ethnicity and nationality has its own problems.

Since you’re thinking of location, “Egypt is an Arabian country” would be gramatically correct, but you’re likely to run into people pointing out that it’s in [Africa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa), not the [Arabian Peninsula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabian_Peninsula).

It might be better to say “Egypt is a country in the [Arab World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arab_world)”. In this case, the word “Arab” qualifies the noun “World”, making it clear that you’re talking about a location.